# Cannot retrieve global variable's value inside function?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting "undefined" as result from returning the variable inside a function.

This is the code:

```
var nloads = 1;
function something(loc) {
    console.log(nloads); // returns 1
}
function changeSection(loc) {
    console.log(nloads); // Returns undefined
    nloads = nloads + 1;
    temp = nloads;
}
```

What's wrong with it?/What may be causing the problem?

Comment: Where do you call those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this pic of code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var nloads = 1;
function something(loc) {

    alert(nloads); // returns 1
}
function changeSection(loc) {
    alert(nloads); // Also returns 1
    nloads = nloads + 1;
    temp = nloads;
}


</script>
<div style="border:solid red; height: 100px;width: 100px;" onClick="something('f');changeSection('f');">   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var nloads = 1;
function something(loc) {
    console.log(nloads); // returns 1
}
function changeSection(loc) {
    nloads = nloads + 1;
    **var** temp = nloads; // I was missing var before declaring the variable
    console.log(nloads);
}
```